# Roll four 6D. Ignore the largest result. Will the sum of the remaining results be less than 8?

Tags: probability, dice, python, programming

I thought I could make an overview of possible outcomes when rolling four dice. So look at possible sums when rolling four dice, 4-24, and which combinations that give these sums. Then one can exclude the largest number in each combination and see which ones give sum less than 8. This took a very long time to do manually and I therefore thought that one might be able to create a python program that produces such an overview. Is there anyone who can help me create such a code?

Comment: The manual approach is do-able, but with minefields.  Consider rolling $(1,2,4,x)$, where $x$ can be $4,5$ or $6$.  Assigning this the *weight* of $3 \times (4!)$ is wrong, because the roll of $(1,2,4,4)$ can only happen in 12 ways, not 24.  As a further complication, ignoring the 4th roll, rolling 3 dice to get $(1,3,3)$ can only occur in $3$ ways, not $3!$ ways.

Comment: What do you do when you get two or more dice show the largest number? Example - all four dice show $1$ then you just take $3$ as sum?

Comment: Assuming that Math Lover's inference of taking $3$ as the sum is correct, and assuming that you want to pursue the manual approach, and noting that this is a probability problem, one approach is to set the denominator equal to $(6^4)$ which represents the number of equally likely rolls.  Then, extending my first comment, $(1,2,4,x)$ would be assigned the weight of $[(2 \times 4!) + (4!/2)]$, while $(1,3,3,x)$ would be assigned the weight of $[(12 \times 3) + (4)].$  In the 2nd weight, the last term indicates that $(1,3,3,3)$ can only occur in 4 ways.